# Spring Accessing data with MySQL Won't Run

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-mvc

I'm new to using Spring, and I'm going through the accessing-data-with-MySQL tutorial [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/). I'm using Eclipse, and when I download all the code for the project, and then run the project as a Spring Boot App, I get the error:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Field userRepository in hello.MainController required a bean of type 'hello.UserRepository' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'hello.UserRepository' in your configuration.

Again, this is the code directly from the tutorial. Anybody have any idea what's going on?

Thanks!

Full run log

```html
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.6.RELEASE)

2017-08-26 21:58:28.365  INFO 2308 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on DESKTOP-F9F09K7 with PID 2308 (C:\Users\dylan\Desktop\gs-accessing-data-mysql-master\complete\target\classes started by dylan in C:\Users\dylan\Desktop\gs-accessing-data-mysql-master\complete)
2017-08-26 21:58:28.367  INFO 2308 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-08-26 21:58:28.411  INFO 2308 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@6b53e23f: startup date [Sat Aug 26 21:58:28 PDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-08-26 21:58:29.454  INFO 2308 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-08-26 21:58:29.465  INFO 2308 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-08-26 21:58:29.466  INFO 2308 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.16
2017-08-26 21:58:29.542  INFO 2308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-08-26 21:58:29.542  INFO 2308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1135 ms
2017-08-26 21:58:29.655  INFO 2308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-08-26 21:58:29.659  INFO 2308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-26 21:58:29.667  INFO 2308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-26 21:58:29.667  INFO 2308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-26 21:58:29.667  INFO 2308 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-08-26 21:58:29.701  WARN 2308 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mainController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'userRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'hello.UserRepository' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
2017-08-26 21:58:29.703  INFO 2308 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-08-26 21:58:29.721  INFO 2308 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-08-26 21:58:29.804 ERROR 2308 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userRepository in hello.MainController required a bean of type 'hello.UserRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'hello.UserRepository' in your configuration.
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this problem by clearing my maven cache. I did  this by manually deleting my:

C:\Users\username\ .m2

folder and then doing a clean install. What the problem was, how it developed, and what changed to fix it I/we may never know. But, things seem to be working again.

Thanks to all who helped!

Answer (score 0):

Have you registered  a repository with type UserRepository? Check if you sign the repository with a @Repository annotation.

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how I'd modify it to sign the repository with a repository announcement. If I put @Repository above the repository definition I'm told Repository cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Is the Repository interface in the package org.springframework.stereotype?
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Repository.html
Type could be it's target.

Comment: Using either org.springframework.stereotype or org.springframework.data.repository.Repository if I then put @Repository above the repository definition, I'm told "Repository is not an annotation type".

Answer (score 0):

1. Download project from git [gs-accessing-data-mysql-master](https://github.com/spring-guides/gs-accessing-data-mysql/archive/master.zip)
2. Extract the file to your disk
3. Open Eclipse
4. Click File > Import > Existing Maven Projects > Next
5. Click Browse and select the `gs-accessing-data-mysql-master` folder that is on your disk and Next
6. Select both pom.xml and Finish
7. Open `gs-mysql-data` project that has been imported
8. Right click on Application.java and run as Java Application or Spring Boot Application

Make sure that `UserRepository` interface extends from `CrudRepository`, like this:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

import hello.User;

// This will be AUTO IMPLEMENTED by Spring into a Bean called userRepository
// CRUD refers Create, Read, Update, Delete

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

}
```

Comment: Assuming that there is no change on the `gs-mysql-data` project. Try this: Right click to `gs-mysql-data` project > Maven >  Update Project

Comment: The UserRepository interface extends the CrudRepository interface in exactly the way defined above, which I think is exactly the way the tutorial does it.

I'm still getting the error.

Comment: Daniel C., are you able to get the code working on your computer?

Comment: yes sure, it is working.  One observation, all my eclipse projects all closed, I'm using java 1.8.  And really its working.  Other observation I also configure the application.properties in order to establish the database connection, but It has no relationship with the error.

Comment: try this: righ click to project -> Run as.. > Click Maven Build > in goal text box put this   `spring-boot:run` and then click on run

Comment: It fails with the same issue.